# Sharepoint 2013 : Client side delete items from list on click of checkbox

Tags: 2013, csom, spgridview

I want to display 30 list items on a page. On checkbox `change` event I want to delete items from a SharePoint list.

I can do this using spgridview server side , but how can this be done client side (csom)?

Answer (score 1):

you can try full rest api and JQuery.

Attach a change listener using jquery to your controls and on that listener you can use the next code

```
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('your_list')/items(your_id)",
    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
    headers: {
        "IF-MATCH": "*",
        "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose",
        "X-RequestDigest":     $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val(),
       "X-HTTP-Method": "DELETE"
    },
    success: function (data) {
         console.log(data);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    },
    complete: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});
```

happy coding :)